# Streaming adaptive audio on the web (low latency)

Tags: html, audio, tcp, udp, web-audio-api

I am attempting to implement a streaming audio solution for the web. My requirements are these:

- Relatively low latency (no more than 2 seconds).
- Streaming in a compressed format (Ogg Vorbis/MP3) to save on bandwidth.
- The stream is generated on the fly and is unique for each client.

To clarify the last point, my case does not fit the usual pattern of having a stream being generated somewhere and then broadcast to the clients using something like Shoutcast. The stream is dynamic and will adapt based on client input which I handle separately using regular http requests to the same server.

Initially I looked at streaming Vorbis/MP3 as http chunks for use with the html5 audio tag, but after some more research I found a lot of people who say that the audio tag has pretty high latency which disqualifies it for this project.

I also looked into Emscripten which would allow me to play audio using SDL2, but the prospect of decoding Vorbis and MP3 in the browser is not too appealing.

I am looking to implement the server in C++ (probably using the asynchronous facilities of boost.asio), and to have as small a codebase as possible for playback in the browser (the more the browser does implicitly the better). Can anyone recommend a solution?

P.S. I have no problem implementing streaming protocol support from scratch in C++ if there are no ready to use libraries that fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Media Source Extension.

Introduction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions
Specification: https://w3c.github.io/media-source/